# bitstamp orderbook using websocket

Tags: python, websocket

The following code written in python uses websocket to get the price of a cryptocoin (ether in USD) in real time, of the bitstamp exchange. It prints in the screen the downloaded information.

```
import pusherclient
import logging

def connect_handler(data):
    trades_channel_ethusd = pusher.subscribe("live_trades_ethusd")
    trades_channel_ethusd.bind('trade', trade_callback_ethusd)

def trade_callback_ethusd(data):
    print(data)

pusher = pusherclient.Pusher("de504dc5763aeef9ff52")
pusher.connection.logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING) 

pusher.connection.bind('pusher:connection_established', connect_handler)
pusher.connect()
```

If I want to do the same with the orderbook, we should change the *"live_trades_ethusd"*  to *"diff_order_book_ethusd"*. (https://www.bitstamp.net/websocket/)

However, when I replace the string it returns nothing. Is it a websocket failure?

***EDIT:***

The right code is:

```
import pusherclient
import logging

def connect_handler(data):
        trades_channel_ethusd = pusher.subscribe("live_trades_ethusd")
        trades_channel_ethusd.bind('data', trade_callback_ethusd)

def trade_callback_ethusd(data):
    print(data)

pusher = pusherclient.Pusher("de504dc5763aeef9ff52")
pusher.connection.logger.setLevel(logging.WARNING) 

pusher.connection.bind('pusher:connection_established',     connect_handler)
pusher.connect()
```

Comment: Is your question correct? You mention changing to ‘live_trades_ethusd’ Did you mean ‘order_book_ethusd’?

Comment: Yes, there was a mistake. Now it is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Short Answer**

Change your `bind` line to the following

```
trades_channel_ethusd.bind('data', trade_callback_ethusd)
```

**Full Answer**

When subscribing to a WebSocket, be sure to bind to the correct Event name. The "previous" call (namely `live_trades_ethusd`)  binds to the "trade" event where as the `diff_order_book_ethusd` call binds to the "data" event